# Dotted point look different when printing on paper

Tags: html, css

Here is my sample printable application form that that allow my user to fill in their information and print it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pritable Document</title>
    <style>
        p{
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        .fillin {
          border-bottom: 2px dotted #888;
          font-weight: bold;
          line-height: 12px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    Name:<span class="fillin">Jonh Nathon</span>
    </p>
    <p>
    Gender:<span class="fillin">Male</span>
    </p>
    <p>
    Date of Birth:<span class="fillin">10-July-1990</span>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

The dotted point (...) as the fillable space looks fine on the browser, however when I print it out, it does not look the same as on browser. It something like a square and asterisk, instead.

[image: Here it look like when I print it]

How can I fix this problem in CSS as I use `border-bottom` style `dotted` already? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the predefined html way to do it!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    u.dotted{
      border-bottom: 1px dashed #999;
      text-decoration: none; 
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
     Name: <u class="dotted">John Nathon</u>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. But when printed, it still look not like on browser.

Comment: try to change another printer

Comment: My friend also try printing on their own printer but still same issue.